# "Package 'graphql' support only TS versions that are >=4.1.0"

Tags: typescript, graphql

When i run the command npx tsc i get the error "Package 'graphql' support only TS versions that are >=4.1.0". But my typescript version is 5.1.6. This is my package.json :

```
    {
  "name": "typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "start": "ts-node index.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "migrate": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./src/migrations/migrations.ts"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.2.0",
    "@next/font": "^13.4.12",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/graphql": "^14.5.0",
    "@types/knex": "^0.16.1",
    "@types/request-promise": "^4.1.48",
    "@types/sqlite3": "^3.1.8",
    "apollo-server": "^3.12.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.12.0",
    "better-sqlite3": "^8.4.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.9",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.4.12",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "graphql": "^16.7.1",
    "graphql-request": "^6.1.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "graphql-tools": "^9.0.0",
    "graphql-yoga": "^1.18.3",
    "next": "^13.4.12",
    "objection": "^3.0.4",
    "prisma": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.2",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.6",
    "sqlite": "^4.2.1",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6",
    "yoga": "^0.0.20"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/accepts": "^1.3.5",
    "@types/better-sqlite3": "^7.6.4",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.2",
    "jest": "^29.6.1",
    "knex": "^2.5.1",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.6",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "^29.1.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/tests/**/*.test.ts"
    ],
    "preset": "ts-jest",
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }
}
```

and this is my tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",                                  
    "module": "commonjs",      
    "outDir": "dist",                         
    "esModuleInterop": true,                             
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,            
    "strict": true,                                      
    "skipLibCheck": true,
                             
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
, "server.ts" ,
"node_modules" ]
}
```

I tried downgrading the typescript version to 4.1.0 , i also deleted my node modules and installed it again.